# Why is this MySQL query so slow to execute?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have provided the PHP query and database table containing real life test data. Why is the MySQL query so slow to execute? Is there anything I can change to speed it up? The execution time is approx 40 seconds and there are approx 2929 records in the table.

Query;

```
$invoice_details_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT i.*, 

ifnull(SUM(ip.invoice_payment_amount),0) as paid, 
(i.invoice_total_amount_exc_vat + i.invoice_total_vat_amount) - ifnull(SUM(ip.invoice_payment_amount),0) as due 
FROM accounts_invoice i 
LEFT JOIN accounts_invoice_payment ip 
ON ip.invoice_payment_invoice_id = i.invoice_id 
WHERE i.invoice_posted='1'
GROUP BY i.invoice_id 
HAVING due>0 
ORDER BY i.invoice_id ASC") or die(mysql_error());

$total = mysqli_num_rows($invoice_details_query);
```

Database structure (no data);

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.6
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: May 12, 2017 at 09:56 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.35
-- PHP Version: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `propsyst_main`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts_invoice`
--

CREATE TABLE `accounts_invoice` (
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_token` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_customer_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_customer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_property_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_tenancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_branch` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_payment_terms` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `invoice_total_amount_exc_vat` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_total_vat_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_posted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `invoice_overdue_reminders` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `invoice_date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date_posted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_posted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `accounts_invoice`
--
ALTER TABLE `accounts_invoice`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `accounts_invoice`
--
ALTER TABLE `accounts_invoice`
  MODIFY `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

EXPLAIN ANALYSE;

```
 Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available. 

Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

explain accounts_invoice



invoice_id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment  
invoice_token   varchar(40) YES             
invoice_customer_type   tinyint(4)  YES             
invoice_customer    int(11) YES             
invoice_date    date    YES             
invoice_due_date    date    YES             
invoice_property_id int(11) YES             
invoice_tenancy_id  int(11) YES             
invoice_branch  int(11) YES             
invoice_payment_terms   tinyint(4)  YES             
invoice_notes   text    YES             
invoice_total_amount_exc_vat    decimal(10,2)   YES             
invoice_total_vat_amount    decimal(10,2)   YES             
invoice_posted  tinyint(4)  YES     0       
invoice_overdue_reminders   tinyint(4)  NO      1       
invoice_date_created    datetime    YES             
invoice_date_updated    datetime    YES             
invoice_date_posted datetime    YES             
invoice_created_by  int(11) YES             
invoice_updated_by  int(11) YES             
invoice_posted_by   int(11) YES
```

Database with real test data;

[Download MySQL data](https://www.property-system-uk.com/accounts_invoice.sql)

Comment: Did you create index? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have just dumped the database structure into the question.

Comment: MyISAM and no indices? That's really not a recipe for success. Use InnoDB whenever possible, it's a proper, transactional, MVCC-capable database engine that's easier to scale, and add indexes on any columns used in a `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @tadman What columns would you suggest adding an index to?

Comment: First create one index for `i.invoice_posted` then another for ` i.invoice_id ` and finally a third one for both in a composite index. Then test result with EXPLAIN PLAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  It sounds like you are missing any index starting with `invoice_payment_invoice_id`.

Also, if only a small fraction of the invoices are posted, then `INDEX(invoice_posted, invoice_id)` would be beneficial.

Comment: Thank you. I have created indexes on invoice_id, invoice_posted and invoice_payment_invoice_id and the query is much faster to execute. Is there anything else you'd recommend to improve performance further?

Comment: I intended for you to have a "composite" index on that last pair, not two separate indexes.  More on [_creating indexes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .